# Live connect to SSAS Tabular from Power BI not working

Tags: powerbi, ssas-tabular

I have a working SSAS tabular model and I want to connect Power BI with live connection to this model. In the model there is a role (READ) for user DOMAIN\aldo. In Power BI desktop everything works fine. I can create report I can see data. In Power BI services I created gateway and successfully connected gateway. Upload to Power BI services was without problems. But despite of this I cannot see data in Power BI services.

Details:
ssas runs on NT service\mssqlserverolapservices
ssas admin technicUser
user in PBI: aldo@boston.com
user in client (according to whoami /upn): aldo@seattle.com (this is user DOMAIN\aldo in SSAS role)
 
mapping done in gateway to replace boston.com with seattle.com
user used in Gateway: technicUser

I can see user aldo@seattle.com in profiler as effective user name

> ```
>     <Catalog>AW</Catalog>
>      <SspropInitAppName>PowerBI</SspropInitAppName>
>      <EffectiveUserName>aldo@seattle.com</EffectiveUserName>
> ```

Error message in POwer BI Services:

> Couldn't retrieve the data for this visual. Please try again later.
>   Please try again later or contact support. If you contact support, please >provide these details.
>   Activity ID8661ae16-5c87-4d04-9049-1e841341f25e
>   Request ID15355511-8ce9-2842-0eea-df1117ecb280
>   Correlation ID3e50c72c-06e8-8c81-8a44-78af1f309549
>   TimeWed Mar 14 2018 14:01:41 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time)
>   Version13.0.4622.132

Any idea what I´m missing to make to work?

Comment: What is your SSAS Version??

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      14.0.17199.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      14.0.1008.227

Comment: I looked into the gateway log and found this error message:

atewayPipelineErrorCode=DM_GWPipeline_UnknownError
ProviderName=MSOLAP.5 --->
Inner exception chain: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
<pi>System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {308FF259-8671-4DF4-B66C-9851BFACF446} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

 

Possible solution is reintall Office web components and that is last posible option for me now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, like you mentioned in your comment. It has to do with the 32 or 64 bit version of the DLL.

```
OLE DB provider 'MSOLAP.5' cannot be instantiated
COMException (0x80040154)
80040154 Class not registered
```

I managed to resolve this by deregistering the 32-bit versions

- “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Analysis Services\AS OLEDB\110\msolap110.dll”
- “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Analysis Services\AS OLEDB\120\msolap120.dll”

and registering the 64 bit version.

- “C:\Program Files\Microsoft Analysis Services\AS OLEDB\120\msolap120.dll”

In a command prompt running as admin you use the regsvr32 command.

To register a dll:

```
regsvr32 <pathToDLL>
```

To unregister a dll:

```
regsvr32 -u <pathToDLL>
```

From reference: [PBI Forums](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/OLE-DB-provider-MSOLAP-5-cannot-be-instantiated-Error-80040154/m-p/148086)